# In an R script, how do I create a sequence using variables for all parameters?

Tags: r

It should be simple enough, but I'm just not finding what I need in the documentation.  I'm sure I just don't know what to look for.

I'm new to R and have started writing a script that will generate a sequence from 3 user input variables.

basically, I want this

```
sequence<-seq(1,10,by=2)
```

to be done with

```
seqStart<-readline(prompt="Sequence Start")
seqStop<-readline(prompt="Sequence Stop")
seqInt<-readline(prompt="Interval")
sequence<-seq(seqStart, seqStop, by=seqInt)
```

Comment: The problem is with the format. What you read into e.g. seqStart is a string but should be numeric or integer for use in `seq`.

Comment: `sequence` is already a function name so you might want to consider naming it something else.

Comment: @Dason Thanks, this was just an example.  I should have used something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the result of readline to numeric:

```
seqStart <- as.numeric(readline(prompt="Sequence Start"))
seqStop <- as.numeric(readline(prompt="Sequence Stop"))
seqInt <- as.numeric(readline(prompt="Interval"))

mySequence <- seq(seqStart, seqStop, by=seqInt)
```

Comment: Simple enough.  I was assuming it had something to do with the way I was trying to use seqInt inline with the "by=" and completely missed the most obvious solution.  Thanks